# Cross tabulate true values only in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "dataAll" and some vars (A,B) on it, I want a table like

```
   A   >10    >20     >30

B

>1

>10

>100
```

To do that, I coded like

with(dataAll, table(A=A>10,B=B>1)) which gives me

```
         A
               FALSE    TRUE
B

        FALSE  220357   4798

        TRUE  596618 210080
```

So, here the value 210080 should go to first cell in the upper table

I tried something like this with no success

with(dataAll, table(A=A>c(10,20,30),B=B>c(1,10,100)))

and even

with(dataAll, table(A=c(A>10,A>20,A>30),B=c(B>1,B>10,B>100)))

but no success,

I know there should be a way to do this...

Comment: @downvoter: If you downvote, you should provide a reason. This question is a common and perfectly valid problem in R related to "recoding" variables.

Comment: @user873096: I edited your question to format the tables better. You just mark the code and/or print output and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A.categ <- cut(A, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, 30, Inf), right=FALSE)
B.categ <- cut(B, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 100, Inf), right=FALSE)
table(A.categ, B.categ)
```

The trick with `cut` is remembering to set right=FALSE, since that is the way most people expect it to work. In fact when Frank Harrell made his version of `cut2` for Hmisc, he set that as the default option.

When you do that with the example cosntructed by Tommy you get

```
> A.categ <- cut(d$A, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, 30, Inf), right=FALSE)
>     B.categ <- cut(d$B, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 100, Inf), right=FALSE)
>     table(A.categ, B.categ)
           B.categ
A.categ     [-Inf,1) [1,10) [10,100) [100, Inf)
  [-Inf,10)        0      1        1          9
  [10,20)          0      2        3          2
  [20,30)          0      5        4          1
  [30, Inf)        0     17       11         44
```

Not every understands the open/closed convention so sometimes you need to go in and rework the `labels` of a factored variable that you constructed with `cut` so the less mathematically inclined client can map it to his conventions. You use the `factor` function and specify the `labels` argument (and do NOT specify the `levels` argument or you will "break the variable")

```
> A.categ <- factor(A.categ, labels=c(" Less than 1", "1-9.9", "10-99.9" , "100+") )
>     table(A.categ, B.categ)
              B.categ
A.categ        [-Inf,1) [1,10) [10,100) [100, Inf)
   Less than 1        0      1        1          9
  1-9.9               0      2        3          2
  10-99.9             0      5        4          1
  100+                0     17       11         44
```

Answer (score 2):

try the cut function.

```
?cut
```

it works with  breaks like you want.

```
cut(x,breaks,labels,...)


 table(cut(A[which(B<1)],breaks=c(0,10,20,30)))


 table(cut(A[which(B>1)],breaks=c(0,10,20,30)))
```

Comment: That is nice workaround, thatnks..And I wanted is total of each cells not in between but having something is better than nothing, i can always make cumulatives out of those..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little `vapply` - based solution. Is assumes you want the total count for each cell (for example, A > 20 & B > 100) - not the count for (A > 20 & A < 30) & (B > 100 & B < 1000).

```
# Create some data
set.seed(42)
n <- 100;
dataAll <- data.frame(A=runif(n, 1,100), B=10^runif(n, 0, 4))

# And some break points    
a <- 1:10*10 # 10, 20 etc...
b <- 10^(0:4) # 1, 10, 100, 1000


f <- function(A, a, B, b) {
    structure(t(vapply(b, function(bb) {
    vapply(a, function(aa, A) sum(A > aa), 1, A[B > bb])    
    }, a)), dimnames=list(B=b, A=a))
}

f(dataAll$A, a, dataAll$B, b)
```

Which gives the following table:

```
       A
B       10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
  1     89 82 72 63 55 46 34 23 16   0
  10    65 60 55 47 41 34 26 18 12   0
  100   47 45 44 39 34 28 21 14 10   0
  1000  20 19 18 17 16 12  8  5  5   0
  10000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

The meat of it all is to count the TRUE values for one `a` condition `sum(A > aa)`, and then do that for all `a` conditions with a call to `vapply`.

```
vapply(a, function(aa, A) sum(A > aa)
```

Then do it again for each `b` condition, and add some dimnames to the (transposed) result.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is exactly what I needed, However, I am getting the "NA" in all cells. I will try to play around the code, as I got the concept...

Comment: I updated the answer so that it uses `dataAll` and wrapped it in a function `f`. ...And if the answer was what you need, you should mark is as an answer. You should also upvote answers (and questions) you like. Just click on the score in the upper left!